# ReactiveUI 7.0, ReactiveCommand, Subscribe never fires?

Tags: xamarin.forms, system.reactive, reactiveui

i'm trying to wrap my head around reactiveUI, which recently updated to 7.0 from 6.5.2, and seems to include some breaking changes regarding ReactiveCommand.

EG this used to work:

in ViewModel:

```c#
 public ReactiveCommand<Unit> DoLogin;

  ...

  DoLogin = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(  
    async x => {
      IsBusy = true;
      await Task.Delay(2500);
      IsBusy = false;
      return Unit.Default;
    });
```

in View:

```c#
      //bind the command
  Observable.FromEventPattern(x => loginButton.Clicked += x, x => loginButton.Clicked -= x)
      .Subscribe(args => ViewModel.DoLogin.Execute(null));

  //do something after the dologin is complete
   this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.DoLogin)
      .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
      .Subscribe( x => {
        DisplayAlert("login complete", "welcome", "OK");
      } 
     );
```

but now in reactiveui 7.0, it is different, i had to make a few changes, and i am unable to get it working properly:

in ViewModel:

```c#
  public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> DoLogin;
  ...
   DoLogin = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(  
    async x => {
      IsBusy = true;
      await Task.Delay(2500);
      IsBusy = false;
      return Unit.Default;
    });
```

in View:

```c#
      //bind the command
  Observable.FromEventPattern(x => loginButton.Clicked += x, x => loginButton.Clicked -= x)
      .Subscribe(args => ViewModel.DoLogin.Execute());

  //do something after the dologin is complete
   this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.DoLogin)
      .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
      .Subscribe( x => {
        DisplayAlert("login complete", "welcome", "OK");
      } 
     );
```

The command code still gets executed, but the WhenANyObservable Subscribe part never fires.  It never shows my DisplayAlert.

I am using Xamarin Forms, if that matters, but even in Windows Forms i get the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that now `Execute()` is a cold observable, so instead of calling

`ViewModel.DoLogin.Execute()`

you have to call

`ViewModel.DoLogin.Execute().Subscribe()`

You can read more about changes in `ReactiveCommand` in the [release docs](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases/tag/7.0.0) (ctrl+F "ReactiveCommand is Better")

By the way - you can probably make your life easier by using bindings in your view in place of having `Observable.FromEventPattern`. This is described in the [docs about ReactiveCommand](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/). That way you will avoid having a `Subscribe` call inside another `Subscribe` call, which is a code smell. The code should be similar to this:

```
this.BindCommand(
    this.ViewModel,
    vm => vm.DoLogin,
    v => v.loginButton);
```

Another sidenote - `ReactiveCommand` exposes `IsExecuting` as an observable property, so you probably don't need a separate flag `IsBusy`,

Comment: yep, great. i managed to work my way through that.  got it much cleaner now.  its tough when trying to learn something that I don't understand, and at the same time the syntax changes!